# Customize all the dialogs in my application

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

I'm writing an Android application but lots of the dialogs I used in Preferences etc have titles which are too long on some smaller screen devices. This causes the text to be cropped which doesn't look great.

Currently my application doesn't define it's own theme, but I'm thinking the solution to my problem is to create a custom theme which extends @android:style/Theme and in that theme I will override the the textSize of the DialogWindowTitle.

I am very new to themes and styles and cannot figure out how to define a theme which extends the default theme and changes only that one style.

Thanks in advance
Craig

Answer (score -1):

Instead of changing the theme you can create your own dialog. This might be simpler than finding the specific style that corrects the DialogTitle.

```
public Dialog createDialogShowMyOrder(String title, String message){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
    final View inflator = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_XML_FILE, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    TextView tit = (TextView)inflator.findViewById(R.id.TITLE_IN_XML);
    TextView mes = (TextView)inflator.findViewById(R.id.MESSAGE_IN_XML);
    tit.setText(title);
    mes.setText(message);
    builder.setView(inflator);

    return builder.create();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem because I am using android.preference.DialogPreference throughout my application as well as creating dialogs when needed. I can't change the title formatting of a dialog created by DialogPreference